# how to display sidebar on pages in wordpress

Tags: pages, sidebar, the-content

I want to display custom field's content in the sidebar on specific pages in WordPress so can anyone have an idea about it then please share it with me.

Thanks In Advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to register the sidebar if you haven`t done yet with `register_sidebar( $args );`, then display it in the page: `dynamic_sidebar( $sidebar );` see documentation at: https://codex.wordpress.org/Sidebars

Comment: I need to display custom field content on sidebar in WordPress

Comment: if you want to display custom field content, you use: get_post_meta(),  see: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/